# Divide PSTricks script into external files

Tags: pstricks

I have a PSTricks picture shown here, where I have tried to move a part of it into a different ´TeX´-file for clarity (not, this is **not** a MWE)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}% set border=0pt at the final stage
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset
{
    dimen=middle,
    offset=.2,
    arrows=|*-|*,
    unit=2cm,% set it to 100cm if you want 1 scale = 100cm = 1m
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](5,1.25)% set showgrid=false at the final stage

\include{ext}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

with `ext.tex`

```
\psframe(1,1)
\psframe(1,.25)(4,.75)
\pscircle(4.5,.5){.5}
```

Why am I not allowed to do this?

Comment: Use `input` see: [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Will you post it as an answer? Then I can mark the question solved

Comment: Why do you need to split it? Probably I can give your an advice. :-)

Comment: @PGFTricks No other reason than to tidy up my files/directory

Comment: Create a package to contain common code that you will reuse in multiple diagrams.